# Shell_NotifyIcon: Tray icon show both - popup menu and taskbar menu

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have created tray icon that displays pop-menu on mouse right click:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA); 
nid.hWnd = (HWND) hWnd;   
nid.uID = 12345;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE;
nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_TRAY_ICON);
nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER_SHELLICON; 
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

hWnd - is main window and it is hidden. There WndProc is look like:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (Message) 
  {
    case WM_USER_SHELLICON: 
    {
      switch(LOWORD(lParam)) 
      {   
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: 
        {
          HMENU hPopupsMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_POPUPS));
          if (hPopupsMenu)
          {
            HMENU hTrayPopupMenu = GetSubMenu(hPopupsMenu, 0);
            if (hTrayPopupMenu) 
            {
              POINT lpClickPoint; 
              GetCursorPos(&lpClickPoint);         
              SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
              TrackPopupMenu(hTrayPopupMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN, lpClickPoint.x, lpClickPoint.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
            }
            DestroyMenu(hPopupsMenu);
          }
        } 
        break;
      }
      break;
    }
...
```

When I right click to tray icon it shows my popup-menu. The problem is that default TaskBar context-menu is shown too. How to fix it?

Comment: Also it is recommended to handle `WM_CONTEXTMENU` instead of mouse click. After all, the context menu could be opened by other means than a mouse click, e. g. via keyboard shortcut. See remarks section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw

Comment: Thanks for answers I'll try to follow your recommendations ;)